# ORA-01789: query block has incorrect number of result columns?

Tags: laravel, oracle, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I have a coding like this. There are two queries and I want to use Union. But I get an error "ORA-01789: query block has incorrect number of result columns". Is there any wrong with my syntax or how?

```
  public function index()
    {
    $medias = DB::connection('oracle')
               ->table('ARCHIVE_LOG_SHEET_HDR AS a')
               ->selectRaw("a.MATERIAL_ID, 'SHOOT' as media_type, '' as media_format, b.HOUSE_NO, a.LOG_DATE, b.FILM_NAME, '' as episode_title, '' as episode_no, '' as last_tx, a.REMARKS, a.LOCATION_ID, c.REMARKS as REMARK_DTL")
               ->leftJoin('ARCHIVE_LOG_SHEET_PROG01 AS b', 'a.LOG_ID', '=', 'b.LOG_ID')
               ->leftJoin('ARCHIVE_LOG_SHEET_DTL AS c', 'a.LOG_ID', '=', 'c.LOG_ID');

   $materials = DB::connection('oracle')
              ->table("STOCK_MATERIAL AS x")
              ->select('x.MATERIAL_ID', 'y.HOUSE_NO', 'x.TXN_DATE', 'y.PROGRAM_NAME', 'w.EPI_NO', 'x.REMARKS', 'x.LOCATION_ID', 'z.remarks',
                       DB::raw("(SELECT TAPET_NAME FROM MA_TAPE_TYPE WHERE TAPET_CODE = x.MATERIAL_TYPE) as media_type"),
                       DB::raw("(SELECT TAPEF_NAME FROM MA_TAPE_FORMAT WHERE TAPEF_CODE = x.MATERIAL_FORMAT) as media_format"),
                       DB::raw("(SELECT MAX (last_date) FROM run_master WHERE run_master.row_id_epi = w.row_id AND run_master.run_aired = Y) as last_tx,"),
                       DB::raw('CASE WHEN x.iden_flag = P THEN y.epi_title WHEN x.iden_flag = C THEN y.prod_version_name WHEN x.iden_flag = M THEN y.promo_name END as episode_title'))
              ->leftJoin('STOCK_MATERIAL_EPI AS y', 'x.MATERIAL_ID', '=', 'y.MATERIAL_ID')
              ->leftJoin('stock_material_slag AS z', 'x.MATERIAL_ID', '=', 'z.MATERIAL_ID')
              ->leftJoin('PUR_EPISODE_HDR AS w', 'y.ROW_ID_EPI', '=', 'w.ROW_ID')
              ->union($medias)
              ->paginate(50);

     return view('ReceiveMedia.index', compact('medias', 'materials'));
 }
```

When running the coding I get an error
[Error Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8yz65.png)

Query 1

```
        SELECT
        ARCHIVE_LOG_SHEET_HDR.MATERIAL_ID as media_no,
        'SHOOT' as media_type,
        '' as media_format,
        ARCHIVE_LOG_SHEET_PROG01.HOUSE_NO as house_no,
        ARCHIVE_LOG_SHEET_HDR.LOG_DATE as entry_date,
        ARCHIVE_LOG_SHEET_PROG01.FILM_NAME as program_name,
        '' as episode_title,
        '' as episode_no,
        '' as last_tx,
        ARCHIVE_LOG_SHEET_HDR.REMARKS as remarks,
        ARCHIVE_LOG_SHEET_HDR.LOCATION_ID as shelf_no,
        ARCHIVE_LOG_SHEET_DTL.REMARKS as short_list
        FROM ARCHIVE_LOG_SHEET_HDR
        LEFT JOIN ARCHIVE_LOG_SHEET_PROG01 ON ARCHIVE_LOG_SHEET_HDR.LOG_ID = ARCHIVE_LOG_SHEET_PROG01.LOG_ID
        LEFT JOIN ARCHIVE_LOG_SHEET_DTL ON ARCHIVE_LOG_SHEET_HDR.LOG_ID = ARCHIVE_LOG_SHEET_DTL.LOG_ID
```

Query 2

```
        SELECT
        x.MATERIAL_ID,
        (SELECT TAPET_NAME FROM MA_TAPE_TYPE WHERE TAPET_CODE = x.MATERIAL_TYPE) as media_type,
        (SELECT TAPEF_NAME FROM MA_TAPE_FORMAT WHERE TAPEF_CODE = x.MATERIAL_FORMAT) as media_format,
        STOCK_MATERIAL_EPI.HOUSE_NO,
        x.TXN_DATE,
        STOCK_MATERIAL_EPI.PROGRAM_NAME,
        CASE WHEN x.iden_flag = 'P' THEN STOCK_MATERIAL_EPI.epi_title WHEN x.iden_flag = 'C'
        THEN STOCK_MATERIAL_EPI.prod_version_name WHEN x.iden_flag = 'M' THEN STOCK_MATERIAL_EPI.promo_name END as episode_title,
        PUR_EPISODE_HDR.EPI_NO,
        (SELECT MAX (last_date) FROM run_master WHERE run_master.row_id_epi = PUR_EPISODE_HDR.row_id AND run_master.run_aired = 'Y') as last_tx,
        x.REMARKS,
        x.LOCATION_ID as shelf_no,
        stock_material_slag.remarks as short_list
        FROM STOCK_MATERIAL x
        LEFT JOIN STOCK_MATERIAL_EPI ON x.MATERIAL_ID = STOCK_MATERIAL_EPI.MATERIAL_ID
        LEFT JOIN stock_material_slag ON x.MATERIAL_ID = stock_material_slag.MATERIAL_ID
        LEFT JOIN PUR_EPISODE_HDR ON STOCK_MATERIAL_EPI.ROW_ID_EPI = PUR_EPISODE_HDR.ROW_ID
```

Comment: Queries joined by UNION or UNION ALL clause do not have same number of columns with same data types. Even if column names are same, different data types will give you below error Can you put only the SQL Query ?

Comment: Each query generates the same number of columns as 12 columns.

Comment: are the columns of the same data type ?? that also produces the error

Comment: I think both of these queries already have the same type of data, because both of those queries I've tried to run with the UNION command in SQL developer and it worked fine. But, when I run into Laravel will still get the error

Answer (score 0):

Screenshot shows `select count(*) ...` which doesn't exists anywhere in your code.

But, you posted the same question on [laracasts.com](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/ora-01789-query-block-has-incorrect-number-of-result-columns) with some more code, and it **does** contain that `count()` function call.

Simplified, it looks like this:

```
select count(*) as aggregate                 --> only 1 column
from stock_material x ...

union 

select a.material_id, 'SHOOT' as media_type  --> 12 columns
from stock_material ...

union

select a.material_id, 'SHOOT' as media_type  --> 12 columns
from archive_log_sheet_hdr ...
```

See the problem? The very first line?

Perhaps you meant to say

```
select count(*) as aggregate 
from
  (select a.material_id, 'SHOOT' as media_type  --> 12 columns
     from stock_material ...
   union
   select a.material_id, 'SHOOT' as media_type  --> 12 columns
     from archive_log_sheet_hdr ...
  );
```